# Condition based Regular expression in Syncfusion Grid

Tags: vb.net, syncfusion

I am working on project on VB 10 and using syncfusion Controls.
working on grid calculation through regular expression. Normal expression in working correct but i want
calculation based on condition. 
using below code :

**Dim Total As New ExpressionFieldDescriptor("Total", "qty * [Rate]-((qty * [Rate])*[Discount(%)]/100)", GetType(Double))**

expected :
**Dim Total As New ExpressionFieldDescriptor("Total", "IF([ismanualamt]= True,"qty" * [Rate] -([Discount Amount]),"qty" * [Rate]-(("qty" * [Rate])*[Discount(%)]/100))", GetType(Double))**

I tried this code also search for alternatives nut didnt found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate Grid aggregate by your own function using ‘customAggregate’ property of Grid. Please find the documentation for your reference.

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/aggregates/?no-cache=1#custom-aggregate